# JavaScript fibonacci using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, fibonacci

Trying to get my fibonacci sequence to work using recursion but am running into the error `maximum callstack exceeded`.

Code:

```
var genFib = function(count, limit, fibArray) {
  if (count === undefined || count === null) {
    var count = 0;
  }

  if (fibArray === undefined || fibArray === null) {
    var fibArray = [0, 1];
  }

  if (count === limit) {
    console.log(fibArray);
    return fibArray;
  }

  var pushFibNo = function(fibArray) {
    fibArray.push(fibArray[fibArray.length - 1] + fibArray[fibArray.length - 2]);
    return fibArray;
  };

  // console.log(count++);
  // console.log(limit);
  // console.log(pushFibNo(fibArray));

  return genFib(count++, limit, pushFibNo(fibArray));

};

genFib(null, 50, null);
```

The three `console.logs` towards the bottom are logging out correct numbers, but I'm still getting the `maximum callstack` error.

Comment: How many numbers (aprox) are you getting before getting the error?

Comment: Found it- you cannot pass in `count++` as a parameter in the return statement towards the bottom, you have to pass in `count += 1`. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: See my answer below, you are always using the same count.

Comment: Both answers are correct

Comment: I think count++ increments by 1 after you send it into the recursive call so you're actually always sending in the initial value, in this case zero. See @janje's answer

Comment: @BrandonKent -- "Tail recursion optimization", the `count++` means that the code have more to execute after the return of the recursion, where the `count +=1` will execute before the recursion -- so the optimizer can remove the call stack in the recursion

Comment: @Soren: I don't think this has anything to do with "tail recursion".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behaviour of `++` is different in postfix and prefix notation.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()):

> If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), then it returns the value before incrementing.
>
> If used prefix with operator before operand (for example, ++x), then it returns the value after incrementing.

This means that you are always passing `count` before incrementing it, resulting in stack overflow.

To solve your problem, change

```
return genFib(count++, limit, pushFibNo(fibArray));
```

To

```
return genFib(++count, limit, pushFibNo(fibArray));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (count === undefined || count === null) {
    var count = 0;
}
```

you have declared "count" again. this overrides the count parameter and the if(count === limit) is never called.

Comment: This is wrong, after the first run `count` is always 0. It does not get redeclared.

Comment: even if the var is inside the if statement, javascript consider it declared in any case. it is true though that the code above has also other problems (see the other solution)

Comment: Good thinking, however, redeclaring a variable will not make it lose its value.

Comment: you're right. it still doesn't look right to declare a variable there but the root of the problem is elsewhere (use of the ++ operator).

Comment: Agreed, that use of `var` is unnecessary and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you was using the postincrement in this line

```
return genFib(count++, limit, pushFibNo(fibArray));
```

Then you always called the fucntion with the same value for "count", if you use the preoperator should works.

```
return genFib(++count, limit, pushFibNo(fibArray));
```